# UVC Lamp causes Atmega 328P to malfunction

Tags: atmega328p, uv

I have got an Atmega328p which connected to a TFT LCD 1.3 inch using SPI. The Atmega 328P is powered through a 5V adaptor. The problem is most of the time when I switched on the UVC Lamp the LCD will stop working and sometimes the Atmega328p also stops working. Even when I connect the UVC lamp directly to the power line, and did not connect it at all to the Atmega328p it still causes malfunction. I have tried adding 680uF capacitor to Atmega 5V and GND but it seems to not solve the problem either. Does anyone know why this happens? And what steps should I take to solve this?

Here is my Schematics:

[image]

I connect the UVC lamp separately and directly to the power lines.

This is the UVC Lamp that I use, I can't seem to find any datasheet for this:

[image]

Yamano UVC Lamp Germicidal

Comment: Do you have a picture of your setup (i.e. a picture of what everything looks like when its assembled together)?

Comment: EMI problem. Show layout. Show decoupling.

Comment: Looks like you have many GPIO pins left open-circuit. How many of these are GPIO-inputs? Can you program them to be outputs? Or at least terminate any that are inputs with pull-up or pull-down resistors.

Comment: @winny , the data cable and the power cable for the uvc lamp was put together closely. May I know which part emitting the EMI? Because I have tried putting the uvc lamp, lamp driver, and its power far away from the system (about 6 feet apart) it still causes malfunction.

Comment: Distancing won’t help. It’s cable conducted. Show your PCB layout. Show your decoupling capacitors in your schematic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments everyone. It seems the problem is indeed EMI and I have used a ferrite beads to eliminate the EMI and it works very well since yesterday. Thank you very much. Now how do I close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While lots of folks are hypothesizing EMI, I would personally suspect that it is the photon flux from the lamp.  A UV germicidal lamp has pretty energetic photons with a pretty solid photon flux.  If you have some chip that isn't sufficiently opaque to the frequency of light emitted, you can get some weird effects.

For example: Xenon flash bulbs could reboot a Raspberry Pi 2 because they would generate carriers in the silicon and flood out the transistors in a power regulator chip.

https://www.alphr.com/raspberry-pi-2/1000375/why-a-camera-flash-will-reboot-your-raspberry-pi-2/

That lamp looks like an actual commercial product for aquariums, so I'm making a big assumption that it had to pass radiated emissions testing somewhere other than China.  Thus, I'm kind of skeptical that it is radiating enough to set off an EMI-caused reboot.

Good luck.